# Relationship between relativistic factor $\gamma$ and Christoffel symbols

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, geodesics

In special relativity, an object moving in a straight line can be described by the statement of zero proper acceleration,

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\gamma \frac{dx}{dt}\right)=0$$.

In contrast, in a curved space a point mass following a geodesic (with zero proper acceleration) satisfies

$$\frac{d^2x^a}{dt^2}+\Gamma^a_{bc}\frac{dx^b}{dt}\frac{dx^c}{dt}=0$$

So clearly the two gammas are related in some ways, but are generally discussed as quite different phenomena - in one sentence each, perhaps "$\gamma$ comes from transforming to different Lorentz frames, whereas $\Gamma$ comes from requiring that various quantities of interest are tensors in all frames".

I'm wondering if one can look at these two expressions and derive a more direct connection between the two gammas. For example, one could guess

$$\frac{1}{\gamma}\frac{d\gamma}{dx^b}\sim\Gamma_b$$

where perhaps $\Gamma_b$ is some contraction of velocities with tetrads or something. Is there a direct way to find this relationship?

Comment: The $t$'s in the equations you're comparing mean two different things.  In the first case they're coordinate time;  in the second they're the particle's proper time.  You can [write out the geodesic equation in terms of coordinate time if you want](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/656802/), but it makes the equations look significantly less similar.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Sure, I agree with that, and I expected part of the answer to include that. And indeed, you could argue that's exactly what @J Murry did in his answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the following, I set $c=1$. The statement of zero proper acceleration is
$$\mathbf A := \frac{d}{d\tau} \mathbf U = 0$$
where $U^\mu = \frac{dx^\mu}{d\tau}$ is the 4-velocity and $\tau$ is the proper time along the particle's worldline.  This can be written in component form as
$$A^\mu = \frac{d^2 x^\mu}{d\tau^2} + \Gamma^\mu_{\alpha \beta}  \frac{dx^\alpha}{d\tau} \frac{dx^\beta}{d\tau} = 0$$
where the Christoffel symbols are defined to be
$$\Gamma^\mu_{\alpha\beta}:= \frac{1}{2}g^{\mu\rho}\left(\frac{\partial g_{\rho \beta}}{\partial x^\alpha} + \frac{\partial g_{\alpha \rho}}{\partial x^\beta} - \frac{\partial g_{\alpha\beta}}{\partial x^\rho} \right)$$
Adopting the $(+---)$ sign convention, the (differential) proper time is defined by
$$\mathrm d\tau^2 = g_{\mu\nu} \mathrm dx^\mu \mathrm dx^\nu \equiv  \mathrm dt^2 /\gamma^2 \qquad \gamma^2 :=\frac{1}{g_{\mu\nu} \frac{dx^\mu}{dt} \frac{dx^\nu}{dt}}$$
where we've singled out the coordinate time $x^0 \equiv t$.  As a result, we can re-express the above statement as
$$A^\mu = \gamma \frac{d}{dt}\left(\gamma \frac{dx^\mu}{dt}\right) + \gamma^2 \Gamma^\mu_{\alpha \beta} \frac{dx^\alpha}{dt}\frac{dx^\beta}{dt} = 0$$

This is as far as we can go without additional information.  As you can see, there is no functional relationship between the $\Gamma$'s and $\gamma$ -they both depend on the metric, but that's about all we can say. For instance, the $\Gamma$'s are functions on spacetime, while $\gamma$ also depends on the state of motion of the particle in question.

If we descend to the realm of special relativity then we may choose Cartesian coordinates, in which the (Minkowski) metric takes the form
$$g_{\mu\nu} = \pmatrix{1 &0&0&0\\0&-1&0&0\\0&0&-1&0\\0&0&0&-1}$$
In this case, we find (a) that all of the $\Gamma$'s vanish, and (b) $\gamma = 1/\sqrt{1 - v^2}$, so our expression reduces finally to

$$A^\mu = 0 \implies \frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2}}\frac{dx^\mu}{dt}\right) = 0$$

Comment: The way you have defined $\gamma^2$ above, it's only valid for special relativity, correct? I've only been able to derive this using $\eta_{\mu\nu}$. I read OP's question and thought it would be sufficient to know that $\Gamma$ collapses under special relativity, rendering no link between the $\gamma$ and $\Gamma$. Is my intuition correct here? Nicely explained, by the way.

Comment: @MichaelBurt Yes, I think your intuition is good. The $\gamma^2$ expression I wrote above is just a definition which, in flat space and cartesian coordinates, reduces to the familiar $(1-v^2)^{-1}$; can you explain what you're trying to derive?

Comment: That makes sense. I just read your post and spent a couple minutes working out that $\gamma^2 d\tau^2 = dt^2$. I'm still fairly new to GR. When I first read your answer I thought you were implying this relationship holds in curved space as well, but now I see you are just showing how this can be used to obtain the expression OP started with.

Comment: @MichaelBurt Right - my goal was to express the geodesic equation in terms of derivatives with respect to the coordinate time $x^0 \equiv t$ rather than the proper time $\tau$; to do that, I essentially *defined* $\gamma := dt/d\tau$.  This definition works just fine in flat or curved space, but the particular form $\gamma=1/\sqrt{1-v^2}$ is just a special case which arises in special relativity.

Comment: @J.Murray Actually, is that possibly an answer here? If you started taking time derivatives of $\gamma=(g_{\mu\nu}dx^{\mu}/dt dx^{\nu}/dt)^{-1}$ you'd end up with first derivatives of the metric, and maybe could use the vanishing of geodesic equation to actually derive the expression for the Christoffel symbols? I don't see it by eye, maybe doing it out carefully....

Comment: @levitopher Well, this is more or less analogous to asking for the relationship between the velocity of a particle and, say, an electric field through which it is moving.  They fundamentally have nothing to do with one another - however, if you have an entire trajectory *and* you assume that the particle is moving only under the influence of the electric field, then by differentiation you can obtain the values of the electric field *along the trajectory*; if you have *every possible* trajectory, then you could find the electric field everywhere.

Comment: @levitopher That being said, it's a mistake (in my opinion) to make the claim that there is a relationship between $\gamma$ and the $\Gamma$'s.  They both appear in the geodesic equation, but that doesn't make them related except in the broadest possible sense - in particular, you can't express one in terms of the other unless you already know the explicit form of the geodesic in question (and all of its neighbors), which is generally speaking the solution to the problem you're trying to solve in the first place.

Comment: @J.Murray: I think I now agree with the idea that there is no relationship between $\gamma$ and $\Gamma$, but not before I saw your answer. By thinking about what $\gamma$ is for a generic metric and spacetime path - that is, the length of the velocity vector - it's more obvious that we should not expect a relationship between them.

Comment: @J.Murray and for the record, I began thinking about this as a result of reading several articles about what metric an observer undergoing proper acceleration would see, for example, https://arxiv.org/pdf/1003.3022.pdf. I find the manner of argument very confusing, and I thought it would have been elucidated by finding the relationship between $\gamma$ and $\Gamma$. The answer now seems "if you don't start with $\Gamma$s in the first place, you should not expect the spacetime to be anything but flat!" (that's actually an entirely different discussion I suppose!)